# WPF App with responsive design

Tags: c#, wpf, responsive-design

I want to make a WPF app which has a different position of its controls depending on the size of the window.

If MainWindow has Width above, let's say 500, then I want my Grid to be 2x2, and if it's below 500, then 4x1 (4 Rows, 1 Column).

First I made 2 Grids, one 2x2, the other 4x1. I have 4 different UserControls, which represent View part of the MVVM. I thought I'd use VisualStateManager with 1 group, which has 2 states, one for defaultGrid, the other for narrowGrid. First state sets Visibility of the first Grid to Visible, and the second to Collapsed, and the other state reversed (Do I even need them both to do that?). I put GoToElementState in the handler for SizeChanged event. I saw this in a book, but they didn't use UserControls, instead they just copied all the controls from the first Grid into the second one and changed the Row and Column properties for each control. I thought that it's possible for 2 different Grids to share 1 UserControl (that was actually the only reason why I put a dozen or so controls/elements in those 4 UserControls in the first place), but so far I've found that that's not possible (although I could be wrong here).

Now, for some controls I guess I don't mind that I technically have 2 instances of each UserControl, because the bindings make them synchronized, but if I type something in the TextBox and change the window size/visual state, then in "that same" TextBox I have different text.

I've come to the conclusion that I don't need VSM at all and that I don't need any other Grids besides the root Grid. In the handler for SizeChanged I've made rootGrid be either 2x2 or 4x1, depending on the window width. In MainWindow.xaml.cs I've also made those 4 UserControls private fields and instantiated them. They are changing their Row and Column properties according to window width. By doing that I now always have only those 4 UserControl instances, that just change their position in the app. (I don't need multiple instances of any of those UserControls).

What I want to know is: Is there any better/more elegant/possibly conventional way of doing this, that I haven't found?

I had the idea of making just 2 UserControls (2 Views) and using VSM to represent them. Both Views would bind to the same properties of the ViewModel. "Synchronization" of inserted text in the TextBox or selected item of a ComboBox would then be done, for TextBox for instance, by binding the Text property of a TextBox, of the first View, to the Text property of a TextBox of the second View. But this doesn't seem like a better alternative.

I also had the idea of making custom converters for Row and Column bindings of  UserControls, but that seemed even worse.

Btw. I'm using C#, VS 2013 and Windows 7. I know UWP have interesting stuff with AdaptiveTriggers in VSM, but I haven't switched to UWP yet, I just started playing with WPF a month ago.

Also I can't use WrapPanel because I need these controls in exactly 2x2 or 4x1 grids. And I can't use UniformGrid because I need them in specific order.

Any input on this would be appreciated.

Comment: A Data Template Selector will probably be your best fit.  You can find out more here: http://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html

Comment: I'm not sure how I would use Data Templates to change the Grid from 2x2 to 4x1 and then put the controls in the corresponding Rows and Columns, but I'll look into that.

Comment: You would simply create two different templates--one with a 2x2 grid and one with a 4x1 grid, and then use the Template Selector to choose the appropriate template, bound to your MainWindow ActualWidth.

Comment: But what about the controls that go into those grids? Can I put a 2x2 Grid, with 4 UserControls inside it, into a template. But then I would have 2 instances of each UserControl, right?

Comment: The templates allow you to define controls multiple times, once for each template--but only the controls in the selected template will get instantiated.  So, no--you would not have 2 instances of each UserControl.

Comment: If only the controls in the selected template get instantiated, then if I change the window size and in doing so change the templates, then wouldn't I get a different instance of each control? If I type something in a TextBox and change the window size/template, would that TextBox actually be the same one, same instance, and have the text that I typed? Or if I select something from a ComboBox and again, change the window size and template, would the ComboBox displayed have that same selected item or would it show me the default one?

Comment: I found a GitHub project (https://github.com/sourcechord/ResponsiveGrid) which seems to do what you are looking for. Basically, it's a Grid control and a set of attached properties that mimics Bootstrap's responsive layout framework.

Comment: Not sure if the [responsive-design](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/responsive-design) tag is applicable to this question. It says in the user guidance that it is for a Web design context, but this is a local application.

Comment: A bit late but worth mentioning that the ResponsiveGrid now is replaced by GridExtra and here is the link to GridExtra: https://github.com/sourcechord/GridExtra